# session object in Fastapi similar to flask

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to use session to pass variables across view functions in fastapi. However, I do not find any doc which specifically says of about session object. Everywhere I see, cookies are used. Is there any way to convert the below flask code in fastapi? I want to keep session implementation as simple as possible.

```
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request, redirect, url_for


app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key='asdsdfsdfs13sdf_df%&'   

@app.route('/a')
def a():
    session['my_var'] = '1234'              
    return redirect(url_for('b'))          


@app.route('/b')
def b():
    my_var = session.get('my_var', None)
    return my_var    


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug = True)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at Starlette's `SessionMiddleware`. FastAPI uses Starlette under the hood so it is compatible.

After you register `SessionMiddleware`, you can access `Request.session`, which is a dictionary.

Documentation: [SessionMiddleware](https://www.starlette.io/middleware/#sessionmiddleware)

An implementation in FastAPI may look like:

```py
@app.route("/a")
async def a(request: Request) -> RedirectResponse:

    request.session["my_var"] = "1234"

    return RedirectResponse("/b")

@app.route("/b")
async def b(request: Request) -> PlainTextResponse:

    my_var = request.session.get("my_var", None)

    return PlainTextResponse(my_var)
```

Comment: I am surprised, no where you have mentioned the set cookie but still I see in browser cookies are set. Can you explain this, why? Using session automatically creates cookies as well?

Comment: When using `SessionMiddleware`, a cookie with a specified name is set. The default name is 'session'. This helps the application identify the session. Other cookies in your browser may not be part of the local application. For example, in Google Chrome there is a cookie with the name of '1P_JAR'. When using `SessionMiddleware`, one cookie is used. Other cookies may be set by other responses.